# Android MediaPlayer gapless video

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play through a sequence of video files using the native MediaPlayer, and cannot have any black flickering between them.

I realize that this issue has been brought up many times before, but the questions are mostly a few years old. Typical responses are swapping between multiple media-players, which doesn't seem to work.

I thought that the widespread use of fragments may have introduced a new solution, and indeed I could get seamless transitions by building a stack of fragments with multiple SurfaceViews visible at the same time, and playing video from the top of the stack down, but of course this is not scalable, as the entire playlist needs to be stored in memory before playback starts.

Just wondering whether anyone has achieved this in recent years? Or would there be any other viable alternative to using SurfaceView or native MediaPlayer?
 I am trying to use a TextureView instead, but currently cannot get it working.

Comment: I used SurfaceView to fix issue with flickering

Comment: Can you give some more details?

Comment: I used VideoView for displaying video content and had issue with flickering. I've used SurfaceView to fix it. Do you need such example?

Comment: Yes it would be awesome if you could post answer or email it to me if it's too long (email is m.harmer@mandoemedia.com).

Comment: It it minor and little fix. I was suprised, that it fixed my issue :) I will post answer in minute

Answer (score 0):

I used below code to fix issue with flickering:

```
<CalculationLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@android:color/black"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_display_journal_fragment_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LinearLayout with id activity_display_journal_fragment_content holds fragment, that contains VideoView.

Comment: Hm, I have seen and tried this suggestion but it did not work.

Comment: How are you swapping between videos? Do you use a separate fragment for each new video?

Comment: In this case, I don't know what to suggest else. SurfaceView made for me magic and fix my issues.

Comment: I have 2-3 videos on page in viewpager. I used 1 fragment

Comment: I see. I'm not using a viewpager, just playing videos in a playlist consecutively. Thanks anyway, I will keep this solution in mind.